# The following packages have been kept back: libsnmp30

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

I'm on Ubuntu 19.10 and am not able to upgrade to 20.04.

When I run `sudo apt upgrade` I get the following response:

```
The following packages have been kept back:
  libsnmp30
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
```

`apt list --upgradable` gives me this:

```
libsnmp30/eoan 5.7.3+dfsg-5ubuntu5 amd64 [upgradable from: 5.7.3+dfsg-1.8ubuntu3.3]
```

I've tried running `sudo apt-get --with-new-pkgs upgrade` to no avail.

Running `sudo apt-get install libsnmp30` gives me:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsnmp30 : Depends: libsensors5 (>= 1:3.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Trying to run `sudo apt-get install libsensors5` then gives me:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsensors5 : Depends: libsensors-config but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

`sudo apt --fix-broken install` also doesn't work.

How can I approach this problem to be able to update to 20.04?
Thanks!